# create 'Date Code' via sql select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use a date code for parts I make that is formatted as follows:

7249

It must be 4 digits. The first digit '7' is the last digit of the current year. The next digits are the days since the first of the year. So today is 9/6, 249 days since the first of the year - '249'.

I am trying to write a sql statement to automate the creation of this 'date code'

So far I have this

```
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1),
             (
                 SELECT(DATEDIFF(dd, '12/31/2016', GETDATE()))
             ));
```

This works, however, it will not fill in any zeros if the date is less than 100 days from 1st of the year. For example on Jan 2, This will produce 72, not 7002.

Please advise on how to add middle zeroes when needed.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DatePart(DAYOFYEAR,date)`

**Example**

```
Declare @D date= '2017-01-02'

Select right(year(@D),1)+right('000'+DateName(DAYOFYEAR,@D),3)
```

**Returns**

**7002**

Or since you are on 2012+

```
Select right(year(@D),1)+format(DatePart(DAYOFYEAR,@D),'000')
```

Comment: Just saw that adding now

Answer (score 0):

you can use `right('00'+doy,3)`  like so:

```
select concat(right(year(getdate()),1)
  ,right('00'+datename(DayOfYear,'20170102'),3))
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LQSR86847

returns `7002`